# Clean Arrow Underline Menu wiht Images

Tags: css, menu

I found this menu in [dynamic drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/clean_arrow_underline_menu/). this worked using CSS Triangles technique. now i need to edited this for images based. my mean replaced images background Instead of CSS Triangles technique in center of `LI` .
HTML :

```
<ul class="arrowunderline">
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/new.htm">New</a></li>
<li class="selected"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/revised.htm">Revised</a></li>
<li><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com">Tools</a></li>
<li><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/style/">CSS</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/">Forums</a></li>   
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
ul.arrowunderline{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center; /* enter "left", "right", or "center" to orient the menu accordingly */
font: bold 16px Georgia;
}

ul.arrowunderline li{
display:inline;
margin-right:25px; /* spacing between each menu item */
}

ul.arrowunderline li a{
position:relative;
color:black;
padding-bottom:8px; /*spacing between each menu item and arrow underline beneath it */
text-decoration:none;

}

ul.arrowunderline li a:hover{
border-bottom:3px solid purple; /* style of arrow underline */
}

ul.arrowunderline li a:hover:after{ /* use CSS generated content to add arrow to the menu */
content:'';
width:0;
height:0;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-5px; /* value should match border-width below */
bottom: 0;
border-width:5px; /* value should match margin-left above */
border-style:solid;
border-color: transparent transparent purple transparent; /* create up arrow */
}
```

IMAGE REPLACE IS : 
[image]

Maybe this way I work. Is there a better way? another way!

Thanks For Any Help.

Answer (score 1):

Give your image in `a:hover:after` instead of border.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/vr7dG/3/

Comment: +1 Yeap! this worked now.Thanks. how to work show image of top menu. really this images in bottom of menu. In fact, if we want to display this image on the top menu Upside down.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wDJWF/

Replaced the css triangle with your image!

Comment: Your method is the simplest form of arthritis, but with the sides of the image is destroyed and the whole picture. Thanks.